# Middleware para autenticação roteando para um vetor já existente em Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-rotas

Estou começando agora a entender o sistema de roteamento do Laravel, e me surgiu uma dúvida referente aos Middlewares. Posso ter dois roteamentos iguais para o mesmo vetor onde, quando meu usuário estiver autenticado o retorno deste roteamento será diferente? Exemplo:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'Página Inicial';
});
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return 'Painel de controle do usuário autenticado';
    });
});
```

Caso não seja possível, qual a melhor maneira de modificar a função de uma rota quando existe um usuário ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente implementar uma condicional que irá verificar se o usuário está autenticado ou não e retornar o controller ou sua função relacionada.

Exemplo:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/'], function()
{
    if(Auth::check()){
        Route::any('/', ['as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'IndexController@index']);
    }
    else{
        Route::any('/', ['as' => 'panel', 'uses' => 'PanelController@index']);
    }
});
```